# How can I make my the colour of non-dairy flan more like a classic flan?

Tags: color, dairy-free, flan

Hello Seasoned Advice community, I'm looking for some flan advice please! Thanks in advance for your answers.

A family member has a dairy allergy, so for several years have been swapping cow milk out of recipes for oat milk.  In the majority of cases, this works fine, but with flans and custards, I've struggled.

I've recently overcome texture issues, but the main problem now is that the flans are always a grey colour - not very appetising! - instead of your classic light brown-yellow flan shade.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make the colour more flan-like without adding colourings?  Or are there any non-dairy alternatives anyone has tried that give you that classic flan hue?

Comment: Are you avoiding all colourings or only the non-naturals ones? An old trick to get food more yellow was to use a little carrot juice, not sure if it will work here.

Comment: @Willeke sounds like an interesting idea, will give carrot juice a go and report back...

Comment: I'm not sure if carrot juice is the way to go here, flan is a delicate flavor and carrot could be noticeable, why not just use caramel coloring?

Comment: I haven’t used oat milk so I don’t know what color it starts as, but coconut milk seems to be the most pure white of the plant milks that I’ve found so doesn’t throw off colors in uncooked dishes.  I don’t know how it browns when cooking, though

Answer (score 0):

A very small amount of turmeric should make it more yellow without affecting the flavor much, if you're concerned about adding artificial food colouring.

Otherwise you could try soymilk? I generally have better results swapping it in for non-dairy milk in recipes; I think the higher protein content gives you better odds of getting the nice caramel-ish color that you want on a flan.